# Attaching and removing events to an event emitter

Tags: javascript

I am writing my own event emitter. I have written a few before but I want to write one that is in the style of `on` and `off` like Node and other systems. I am stuck in trying to understand how I could use `off` to remove a listener to an event emitter. This is because when `on` is called, I don't see how I can provide or generate a unique `id` to this listener.

**EventSystem**

```
class EventSystem {
    constructor(sender){
        this.sender = sender;
        this.events = {};
        return this;
    }

    create(name){
        return this.events[name] = { callbacks : [] };
    }

    on(name, callback){
        var event = this.events[name];
        if(!isDefined(event))
            event = this.create(name);

        event.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    off(name){

    }

    emit(){
        var event = this.events[arguments[0]];
        if(isDefined(event)){
            var args = arguments.slice(1, arguments.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < event.callbacks.length; i++){
                event.callbacks[i](this.sender, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some Class**

```
class Foo {
   constructor(){
     this.evs = new EventSystem(this);
     return this;
  }
  do(){
     this.evs.emit('do', arg1, arg2, arg3);
   }
}

var foo = new Foo();

foo.on('do', function(sender, arg1, arg2){
    console.log(arg1);
});

foo.do();

foo.off('do');
```

How can I assign some kind of ID when using `.on` so that I can use `.off` ?

Comment: why do you need an id? use `indexOf()` to find the handler in `event.callbacks` and splice it out.

Comment: How is this possible? What if two people are listening to an event with the same anonymous function callback? Not the exact same function, but written verbatim.

Comment: that's why you have to pass the name and function itself to `off()` you find the function in the pool under the name and remove it. if there's more than one handler needed, than don't remove it, or add many handlers as-needed (they are cheap)

Comment: Suppose two classes listen to `create` using their own, but otherwise identical anon functions. `foo.on('create', function(a,b,c){ console.log(a)};` Will it know the difference?

Comment: yes, it magically will know the difference because the code that calls `off()` remembers (or should anyway) the corresponding function that was added.

Comment: Ok - that is pretty incredible. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to implement namespace feature like in Jquery? Like below

```
    $("#element").on("click.myNamespace", function() { 
      console.log("doSomething");
    });

    $("#element").off("click.myNamespace");
```

Comment: No I wasn't trying to do that. I don't want to have all my classes use jquery.

Comment: You know what.. you're right. This is what I am trying to do. If I called `.off('eventName')` everyone would be unsubscribed. But if I pass a namespace it can be used like an ID... !